# jQuery UI range slider with letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery UI Range slider like below working fine (pretty much a copy and paste from the jQuery API examples:

```
//Price range slider
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 300,
        max: 18499,
        values: [300,18499],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount-price" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount-price" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - £" + $( "#slider-range-price" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

However now i need a second one, but this time i need it to handles letters instead of integers.
As such i need the min: 'A' and the max :'Z', so that the range is 2 letters of the alphabet.
But i have been unable to find anything other than integers or floats for sliders.
Any help appreciated - bearing in mind i have done a lot of web-dev, but am pretty new to jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` values which equate to the ASCII keycodes for `A` and `Z` respectively, then use `String.fromCharCode()` in the `slide` event to display them. Try this:

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 65,
  max: 90,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#display').text(String.fromCharCode(ui.value));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

#display {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Alternatively, if you need the values sent to the server to be between `1` and `26`, you can amend the ASCII code within the `slide` func:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 26,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#display').text(String.fromCharCode(ui.value + 64));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an array for that, which maps integer values to letters in the alphabet.

```
var alph = ["A", "B", "C", ..., "Z"];
```

So user ranges between 0 to 25. Then you display the letter from the array which corresponds to the selected integer. For example: `alph[2] // C`

```
var alph = ["A", "B", "C", ..., "Z"];
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0, // A
  max: 25, // Z
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#display').text(alph[ui.value]);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think of this simple solution. although i think i prefer the ASCII one below because it avoids creating an array of letter each time - but good workaround all the same

Answer (score 0):

There's two good solutions already, and here's a third alternative: use [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) with base 36, and restrict the min and max values to between A and Z:

```
$( "#slider-range-price" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 35,
    values: [ 20, 26 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount-price" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ].toString(36) + " - " +
                                  ui.values[ 1 ].toString(36) );
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rapo71L1/)